# Set value to a hidden field using jquery not working during AutoComplete

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

There's this simple form, which sends `get-request` to the server.

```
<form id="form0" method="get">
  <input id="searchTerm" type="hidden" name="searchTerm">
  <input type="search" id="userSearchTerm" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And I use jquery-ui `auto-complete` to get the json data from the server and yes, it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#userSearchTerm").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/AutoComplete",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("successfully got the data");
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { name: item.name, value: item.age };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.name);
            $('#searchTerm').val(ui.item.name);
            $("#form0").submit();
        }


    });
    return false;
})
```

I get the alert messages like "**successfully got the data**" as well as the "**item name**". Also checked with `Network` tab under Google Chrome -> the json response is there.

The problem is that, I cannot make the form submit. If I remove the line, `$('#searchTerm').val(ui.item.name);` the form is getting submitted and everything's fine.

Could any one point me in the right direction? Why not this simple javascript is not running?

Comment: Where is your sort2 defined? Or from where its coming?

Comment: @Jatinpatil: thanks for pointing out. It was a typo. But, still the same error.

Comment: It looks like evrything is fine. can you create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with sample json?

Comment: Have you checked for client side errors in debugger?

Comment: @Unknown: sure..creating it.

Comment: Do you have `multiple elements` with **same id searchTerm**?

Comment: @Jatinpatil: sorry, but how do i do that ?

Comment: @RohanKumar: did a quick search and no

Comment: @Unknown: I have created a basic JSFiddle. But, it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/sNb86/

Comment: To check for client side errors. if you are using ie press f12 and in developers tool you can see all console errors. and in mozzila you will have to install plugin linke firebug.

Comment: your example is not match with your question and also not enough , errors also in your  example , what exactly want you?

Comment: You have to pass tags like this `source: availableTags` not `source: {availableTags}`. Working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/sNb86/4/

Comment: ui.item.name is undef in your fiddle...

Comment: @Unknown: Great thanks for the edit. I again tried setting a value to the hidden field in http://jsfiddle.net/sNb86/6/. But, i get an error in the console as `Object [object Object] has no method 'value' `

Comment: @MikeP. Thanks for pointing out that. I tried, `  $("searchTerm").value("test");` even then the form does not submit.

Comment: You have typo. It's not `$("searchTerm").value("test")`. Use `$("searchTerm").val("test")` .http://jsfiddle.net/sNb86/7/

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Use ui.item.value instead, you should be all set.

Comment: @Unknown: Exact, and you just rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (e, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.value);
                $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#form0").submit();
            }
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sNb86/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace **ui.item.name** to **ui.item.value** like,

```
 select: function (e, ui) {
     alert(ui.item.value);
     $('#searchTerm').val(ui.item.value);
     $("#form0").submit();
 }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNb86/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Unknown, @Rohan, @Mike, @Jatin who pointed me in right direction and for the jfiddle efforts they put.

So, a couple of things that I learnt a lesson: Time to answer `"Why it did not work?"`

Well, the answer is:

There was an input field of type `"hidden"` with **id = SearchTerm** and I was trying to set the value to it before form submission.

I used something like,

```
 $("#searchTerm").value("TEST");
```

It seems that the browser is not happy telling me that, **`Object [object Object] has no method 'value'`**.

Hence, the proper way to set the value to a hidden field in a form using `jquery` is to use something like this:

```
$('input[name=searchTerm]').val(ui.item.name);
```

And the second part:

My JSON object is of type, **`name and value pairs`**. So, typically I should be using,

```
$('input[name=searchTerm]').val(ui.item.name); or $('input[name=searchTerm]').val(ui.item.value);
```

and not just `$('input[name=searchTerm]').val(ui.item); //This is not sensible.`

**Additional Notes:**

You can press F12 to bring up the developer tools (this wont be launched if firebug is installed).

Navigate to `Console tab` which brings you the various script errors.

Navigate to `Network tab` which brings you all the JSON requests.